# Pointer/Refer to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Okay, I'm writing a program that will perform different functions on an array. If necessary, the array will need to change capacity. The instructions are:

1. Create an new array.
2. Copy the contents from the old array to the new.
3. Delete the old array.

This part is understand, but what I don´t understand is how to keep a reference to the array that the functions will work with. This is my code for creating a new array and move over the elements.

```
  int newSize = m_size*2;

  double *tempArray= new double[newSize];
  for(int i=0; i<m_size-1; i++)
  {
     tempArray[i] = arr[i];
  }

  delete []arr;
  for(int i=0; i<m_size-1; i++)
  {
     arr[i] = tempArray[i];
  }

  delete []tempArray;

 }
```

All the other methods use **arr** so I would like to reference back to that. A pointer won´t work since it only points to the first element. How can I use my arr variable to refer to an array?

Comment: i think delete []arr should be arr = new ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got **undefined behaviour** in your code.

```
delete []arr;
for(int i=0; i<m_size-1; i++)
{
   arr[i] = tempArray[i];
}
```

You delete the memory arr was pointing to and then assign to the deleted memory inside the loop. Instead you should just write:

```
delete []arr;
arr = tempArray;
```

The whole code would be:

```
int newSize = m_size*2;

double *tempArray= new double[newSize];
for(int i=0; i<m_size-1; i++) // -1 might be wrong, look below for a comment on this line.
{
   tempArray[i] = arr[i];
}

delete []arr;
arr = tempArray;
m_size = newSize // stolen from the others *cough* since I oversaw the need.
// note that I don't call delete on tempArray.
}
```

Also I don't know how you allocated your first array but if you made it calling `new double[m_size]` then you'd want to delete the `-1` in the loop condition of the for loop since you're checking for `i < m_size` and not `i <= m_size`.

Comment: This did seem to solve my problem, thank you. However, why would you not delete the tempArray?

Comment: @marsrover `tempArray` is just meant as a temporary pointer to the new array while copying the old data over. After that you'll make `arr` point to that memory block, so you'll still need to be able to reach it (deleting it wouldn't allow you to still access it).

Comment: @marsrover also hope you noticed my last edit where I added `m_size = newSize` (others had that part already but I forgot that we have to keep track of the new size in my answer at first).

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++ dynamic arrays are usually represented by a pointer to the first element and the number of elements. So I'm assuming the following declarations:

```
double *arr;
int m_size;
```

If by any chance you have `arr` decleared as a real array `double arr[..]`, then you cannot do `delete []arr` nor change its size!

Then your code should be along the lines of:

```
int newSize = 2*m_size;
double *tempArray= new double[newSize];
for(int i=0; i<m_size-1; i++)
{
   tempArray[i] = arr[i];
}
delete []arr;
arr = tempArray;
m_size = newSize;
```

But now I wonder: why `m_size-1` in the loop?

And also, you can just do:

```
memcpy(tempArray, arr, sizeof(*arr) * m_size)); //or m_size-1?
```

All this is nice if it is an exercise. For real code it almost always better to use `std::vector<double>` and the `resize()` member function.

Comment: ".. why m_size-1 in the loop?" - because `m_size` is the *existing* allocation magnitude of `arr`. It may have been more apparent as `std::copy(arr, arr+m_size, tempArray);` but knowing that the OP would likely have been using `std::vector<>` in the first place.

Comment: @WhozCraig: But then the last element of the array (`arr[m_size-1]` is not copied! Or am I missing something (no pun intended)?

Comment: You're not missing something at all. You're absolutely right. I really need at least two cups of coffee before posting comments on SO so early in the morning. (and I was the initial +1 on this answer, btw).

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for ar after deallocating it.

```
int newSize = m_size*2;

double *tempArray= new double[newSize];
for(int i=0; i<m_size-1; i++)
{
   tempArray[i] = arr[i];
}

delete []arr;
ar = new double[newSize];
for(int i=0; i<m_size-1; i++)
{
   arr[i] = tempArray[i];
}

delete []tempArray;
```

Comment: The entire second half of this past `delete[] arr;` can be replaced by simply `arr = tempArray;`. And you need to update `m_size` as the new size, `m_size = newSize;`

Answer (score 0):

```
delete []arr;
for(int i=0; i<m_size-1; i++)
{
 arr[i] = tempArray[i];
}
```

Oops. Don't access after delete. And don't delete unless it was allocated with new.

You simply can't reallocate an array declared as

```
int arr[100]
```

or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've given, what you're currently performing is:

1. Create a new array (`tempArray`)
2. Copy the contents of the old (`arr`) array to the new (`temp`) - (note - what happens if you make the new array smaller than the old?)
3. Delete the old array
4. Copy the new values back into the deleted remains of the old array (note - you deleted `arr` so you can't use it now!)
5. Delete the new array (so everything is gone)

Basically, you need to fix step 2, to handle sizes, and get rid of steps 4 and 5 entirely - you just need to re-assign `arr` instead:
`arr = tempArray`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to declare the  array arr and put the values in it. You can refer to the array through its pointer arr or each element with arr[element_id].

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here:

1. Take the C-style approach of just storing the pointer to the first element like you have, plus the length. From those two you can calculate anything you need.
2. Use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). It holds an array, allows you to easily resize it with functions like `emplace_back`, and can tell you its length with the `size` function.

The second approach is certainly preferred. If you're in C++, you should usually be using `std::vector` instead of raw arrays, unless you're looking for a fixed-sized one. In that case use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

You also get the added benefit of copying a vector being as simple as `vector1 = vector2;`.

Comment: I'd guess this is a homework assignment, so "reinventing the wheel" is what's wanted